# Display upload percent through javascript just like bottom-left of chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, file-upload

Whenever you upload a file/files through chrome, it will display the upload percent in the bottom left corner of the page before hitting 100% and redirecting.

Where does Chrome get this number and how can I display the value on the page through javascript/jQuery (on all browsers) before the page redirects?

I have searched around and I don't want to upload a file through AJAX, just use a regular form  such as...

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/submit">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: If you want to display the upload progress on the page, you'll have to use some sort of AJAX setup.

Comment: @Blazemonger How does Chrome get the number?

Comment: It doesn't matter; if it's not exposed through JavaScript, you can't put it inside your webpage.

Comment: Ha, I was wondering the exact same thing - fantasising about how convenient it would be if that value were exposed.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing thus far, if the form is posted using a traditional request.method.POST method, the progress bar shows up.